# SQLzoo more JOIN execerise #16

Tags: sql, join

I am working on the more JOIN operations with the movie database. My question is on problem #16: List all the people who have worked with 'Art Garfunkel'

You need to first fetch all movies in which Art Garfunkel is in as one value and then fetch all the names of people who were in the same movies by comparing it to the first value.

I came up with my own query and by logic it is supposed to work but does not due to a timeout (which I am assuming is due to an inefficient query)

My query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.name
FROM actor a
JOIN casting b ON (a.id=b.actorid) 
JOIN movie c ON (b.movieid=c.id)
WHERE c.title IN(SELECT z.title
FROM movie z
JOIN casting y ON (z.id=y.movieid)
JOIN actor x on (y.actorid=x.id)
WHERE x.name='Art Garfunkel')
```

Another version:

```
SELECT DISTINCT actor.name
FROM movie,actor,casting
WHERE movie.id=casting.movieid
AND actor.id=casting.actorid
AND movie.title IN(SELECT movie.title
FROM movie,actor,casting
WHERE movie.id=casting.movieid
AND actor.id=casting.actorid
AND actor.name='Art Garfunkel')
```

Both of these throw a parse error saying that there was a timeout attempting to query whatever is shown above.

The version of query they provided that was accepted as an answer is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.name
FROM actor d JOIN casting a ON (a.actorid=d.id)
   JOIN casting b ON (a.movieid=b.movieid)
   JOIN actor c ON (b.actorid=c.id 
                AND c.name='Art Garfunkel')
  WHERE d.id!=c.id
```

Is my logic entirely wrong here? Or is it that the query is simply very very inefficient (which I am thinking). Is there a way to fix it to run and get the correct answer? Or should I be thinking more logically the way the correct query does it?

So many questions but I wanted feedback on why that query did not work and what the next step is.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the answers to all of the sql zoo questions:
[answers](http://www.gideondsouza.com/blog/solutions-to-sqlzoo.net-more-join-operation-questions-movie-database#.UUZEXhylGu8)

```
SELECT a.name
 FROM casting c JOIN actor a ON
  a.id = c.actorid
 WHERE 
  a.name <> 'Art Garfunkel' AND
  c.movieid 
 IN (
  SELECT m.id
     FROM casting c JOIN movie m ON
       m.id = c.movieid
     JOIN actor a ON
       c.actorid = a.id
     WHERE a.name = 'ART Garfunkel'
)
ORDER BY a.name
```

Comment: The given query actually does not work either. It returns the same parse error I mentioned above. That's why I was confused as to why the bottom query I mentioned worked but the two I wrote did not

Comment: it is an error on their side, try email ing them with their email

Comment: If we're looking for "all people", shouldn't directors be included in the query?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my query and a clear explanation of how to derive it.

Step 1: Get all the `movieids` of Art Garfunkel

```
select movie.id 
from actor 
     join 
     casting on actor.id=casting.actorid 
     join 
     movie on movie.id=casting.movieid
where actor.name='Art Garfunkel'
group by movie.id
```

Step 2: Now from those list of `movieids` get all the actors in those movies.

```
  select actor.name 
  from casting 
       join 
       actor on casting.actorid=actor.id 
       join 
       movie on movie.id=casting.movieid
 where casting.movieid in
                       ( select movie.id 
                         from actor 
                              join 
                              casting on actor.id=casting.actorid 
                              join 
                              movie on movie.id=casting.movieid
                         where actor.name='Art Garfunkel'
                         group by movie.id
                      )
```

Step 3: We need co-actors to `'Art Garfunkel'` so Eliminate `'Art Garfunkel'` from resultset

```
     select actor.name 
     from casting 
           join 
           actor on casting.actorid=actor.id 
           join 
           movie on movie.id=casting.movieid
     where casting.movieid in
                           ( select movie.id 
                             from actor 
                                  join 
                                  casting on actor.id=casting.actorid 
                                  join 
                                  movie on movie.id=casting.movieid
                             where actor.name='Art Garfunkel'
                             group by movie.id
                          )
   and actor.name!='Art Garfunkel'
```

Answer (score 0):

well, it took me a couple of hours to really figure this one (Number-16) out, as the suggested solution does not make sense at first sight (neither at second).
However, I managed to figure it out after I came up with my own solution, which is more comprehensible (I feel).
So first my solution:

```
select name from actor 
join casting on actor.id=actorid
where movieid in
(select movieid from casting
join actor on actorid=actor.id
where name='Art Garfunkel')
and name <>'Art Garfunkel'
```

I search for all the actorids (= outer select) for those movieids in which Art Garfunkel had a role (inner select) and then I filter out Art Garfunkel himself.

Simple enough.

You could add the following line at the end of the query, which would be nice:

```
order by name
```

but then the query is not accepted any longer as correct.

As it frets me when I don't understand another's solution I spent some time on the one given elsewhere.
Here it is again:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.name
FROM actor a 
JOIN casting b ON (a.id=b.actorid)
JOIN casting c on b.movieid=c.movieid
JOIN actor d ON (c.actorid=d.id 
                AND d.name='Art Garfunkel')
WHERE a.id!=d.id
```

Interestingly enough you could write this slightly different and take the where clause out of the last join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.name
FROM actor a 
JOIN casting b ON (a.id=b.actorid)
JOIN casting c on b.movieid=c.movieid
JOIN actor d ON (c.actorid=d.id)
WHERE d.name='Art Garfunkel' 
AND a.id!=d.id
```

In any case, you have to LOOK AT THIS QUERY BACKWARDS otherwise it never makes sense. 
This seems to be what happens:

**actor-d** (or the first part of the Where clause, which seems to be evaluated first) sets (or limits to) Art Garfunkel and passes this back to **casting-c**.
**casting-c** looks up the movieids from Art Garfunkel (which by the way are two: 1412 for catch-22 and 1597 for Boxing Helena) and sets these as a filter for **casting-b**—as **casting-b** takes them over.
**Casting-b** then—with the filter set to those two movies from Garfunkel—reverts back to all actorids in **actor-a**, where the names of all the actors having starred in these two movies are looked up.
Finally, Art Garfunkel is filtered out—and that's it.

It feels to me as if this would be some machine code, as if some query-opimizer has come up with it. 
A sensible human being would not think along these lines (at least I wouldn't).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name
  FROM movie, casting, actor
  WHERE movieid=movie.id
    AND actorid=actor.id 
and movieid IN
    (SELECT movieid FROM casting, actor
     WHERE actorid=actor.id
     AND name='Art Garfunkel')and name <>'Art Garfunkel'
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, a few words of explanation will help current and future readers understand this answer even better.

Answer (score 0):

The following is the SQL answer given above:

```
SELECT a.name from actor a 
inner join casting c on a.id=c.actorid 
inner join movie m on m.id=c.movieid 
WHERE m.id in (SELECT c.movieid from casting c inner join actor a 
on a.id=c.actorid WHERE a.name='Art Garfunkel') 
and a.name<>'Art Garfunkel'
```

However, as a SQL beginner who is still getting used to unions, the first code I came up with was the following:

```
SELECT name from actor WHERE id IN 
(SELECT actorid from casting WHERE movieid IN (SELECT movieid 
from casting WHERE actorid IN (SELECT 
id from actor WHERE name='Art Garfunkel'))) 
and name<>'Art Garfunkel'
```

It essentially does the same thing as the explanation above- The **SELECT id** statement finds Art's actor id. **SELECT movieid** finds the movies he was in. **SELECT actorid** finds the other actors in those movies, while **SELECT name** finds their names.

Learning how to do unions is ideal and I did end up with the inner join syntax, but just throwing the other answer in for SQL users who are more comfortable with SELECT or are still learning about unions.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that works is the following:

```
SELECT name
FROM casting
JOIN actor ON actor.id=actorid
WHERE movieid IN (SELECT movieid FROM casting WHERE actorid = 
   (SELECT id FROM actor WHERE name='Art Garfunkel'))
GROUP BY actorid
HAVING name<>'Art Garfunkel'
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought this question was similar to the Julie Andrews item (#13 currently on [sqlzoo](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/More_JOIN_operations)), so I've basically adapted [Bill Karwin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20860/bill-karwin)'s elegant [solution to the Julie Andrews problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434013/how-do-i-list-the-first-value-from-a-three-way-joined-table-query) to solve this problem in an admittedly less elegant manner. This solution does use all `JOINs` which seems to be the point of this set of exercises. Essentially, the way I conceptualized this is that Art Garfunkel was cast in a movie where other people were also cast. In other words, Garfunkel <-> casting <-> movie <-> casting <-> co-star names.

I'm an extremely new SQL user (honestly, <24 hours) so this may be clunky but it worked for me:

```
SELECT a2.name
FROM actor a1
JOIN casting AS c1 ON (a1.id = c1.actorid)
JOIN movie ON (c1.movieid=movie.id)
JOIN casting AS c2 ON (movie.id=c2.movieid)
JOIN actor AS a2 ON (c2.actorid=a2.id)
WHERE
    a1.name='Art Garfunkel'
    AND a2.name <> 'Art Garfunkel'
GROUP BY a2.name
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why one needs to join the movie table in this query. The task in this exercise is to list actor names only, not names and titles (which would require to join the movie table as well). I came up with the following query, and it worked. :)

```
SELECT name 
FROM actor 
JOIN casting on actor.id = actorid 
WHERE name <> 'Art Garfunkel' 
AND movieid IN 
(SELECT movieid 
FROM casting 
JOIN actor on actorid = actor.id 
WHERE name = 'Art Garfunkel')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.name FROM actor a 
    JOIN casting c ON a.id=c.actorid 
    JOIN movie m ON c.movieid=m.id
    WHERE c.movieid IN 
        (SELECT movieid FROM casting WHERE actorid IN
            (SELECT id FROM actor WHERE name = 'Art Garfunkel')) 
    AND a.name <> 'Art Garfunkel'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your both solutions are not entirely wrong. You just need to add one more condition to your sql. `List all the people who have worked with 'Art Garfunkel'` it means to find only those who worked with `'Art Garfunkel'` but in your sql you don't exclude `'Art Garfunkel'` from the list that's why sqlzoo say your solutions are wrong.

here is your modified version:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.name
 FROM actor a
             JOIN casting b ON (a.id=b.actorid) 
             JOIN movie c ON (b.movieid=c.id)
 WHERE c.title IN(SELECT z.title
                   FROM movie z
                                JOIN casting y ON (z.id=y.movieid)
                                JOIN actor x on (y.actorid=x.id)
                   WHERE x.name='Art Garfunkel') 
 AND a.name <> 'Art Garfunkel'
```

`AND a.name <> 'Art Garfunkel'` is added to your original sql

your solution #2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT actor.name
 FROM movie,actor,casting
 WHERE movie.id=casting.movieid
       AND actor.id=casting.actorid
       AND movie.title IN(SELECT movie.title
                           FROM movie,actor,casting
                           WHERE movie.id=casting.movieid
                                 AND actor.id=casting.actorid
                                 AND actor.name='Art Garfunkel')
       AND actor.name <> 'Art Garfunkel'
```

`AND actor.name <> 'Art Garfunkel'` is added to your original sql

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to this is -
`select distinct(name) from movie 
join casting on movie.id=movieid
join actor on actor.id=actorid where name not in ('Art Garfunkel') and title in (select title from movie 
join casting on movie.id=movieid
join actor on actor.id=actorid where name ='Art Garfunkel')`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, a few words of explanation will help current and future readers understand this answer even better.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT name
FROM actor, movie, casting
WHERE name <> 'Art Garfunkel'
AND movie.id = casting.movieid AND casting.actorid = actor.id
AND movieid IN (
SELECT movieid 
        FROM casting, actor 
        WHERE actor.id = actorid AND name = 'Art Garfunkel'
)
```

Comment: When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users if you included some context to explain how your answer helps. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).